# HttpClient - supporting gzip

Tags: java, httpclient

Is it easy to add gzip support to an existing codebase?  This is a string based (JSON) API, where the client just makes a requests and parses the JSON data returned.  It'd be great if I could add gzip support to this.

I'm using HttpClient 4.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the [HttpClient examples](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html) shows how to do this : see custom protocol interceptors.